# Equivalencia de java en .NET

Tags: c#

¿alguien sabe como podria utilizar el siguiente código de java en C# .NET?

```
URL url = new URL(l_url);
URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlCon.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que estas queriendo hacer?

Comment: Estoy migrando de java a c# y quisiera saber cual es la equivalencia en C# para esas líneas de código.

Comment: o sea.. como hacer un get a una url?

Comment: si, lo que hace esas líneas de código es obtener algo por medio de una url que le envío

Answer (score 0):

Segun tu codigo, entiendo que estas queriendo descargar un stream y en c# podrias hacer asi:

```
 public async void Get()
 {
   httpClient client = new HttpClient();
   var response = await client.GetStream(url);
 }
```

Con esta clase podes descargar string, stream, etc.

Answer (score 0):

lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
HttpWebRequest loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(l_url);

HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loHttp.GetResponse();

Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

string texto = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

loWebResponse.Close();

loResponseStream.Close();
```